Getting tabular data into a dataframe from a PHP webpage
This webpage ('*https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/top-gainers-losers*') has 2 tables ('gainers' and 'losers').
I want a code to read the contents of the webpage and download these 2 tables into 2 separate dataframes. How do I achieve this?

Welcome to [so]. Please read How To Ask a Good Question. "please help me" is not a question; we don't write code to specification. You are expected to study the problem ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.

I saw many question on Stackoverflow which had url nseindia. Maybe you can find some question. Even today I saw one of two question with nseindia

if web page doesn't use JavaScript and keep data in <table> then you can try to use pandas.read_html(url) - and this could give list with all <table>

if page uses JavaScript then you may need to use Selenium to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.

This page has button Download .csv and after downloading in Firefox I can go to Download Manager and use Copy Download Link to get link to this CSV - I didn't tested if I can read it with pandas.read_csv(url) or requests.get(url). I expect it may need special headers in requests - and even some API key. https://www.nseindia.com/api/live-analysis-variations?index=gainers&type=NIFTY&csv=true

This page uses JavaScript to generate page so normally it would need Selenium to control real web browser which can run JavaScript
But there is button Download .csv which allows to download table as CSV.
But it doesn't have URL - only onclick="downloadCSVFile('loosers')" - and maybe using downloadCSVFile('loosers') in Selenium you could download it.
But I downloaded this file in Firefox, and I opened Download Manager in Firefox, and I selected downloaded file and using Copy Download Link I got link to this file:
gainers:
https://www.nseindia.com/api/live-analysis-variations?index=gainers&type=NIFTY&csv=true
loosers:
https://www.nseindia.com/api/live-analysis-variations?index=loosers&type=NIFTY&csv=true
Next I tested if I can download it with requests
import requests

session = requests.Session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:125.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/125.0'}

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/top-gainers-losers'
response = session.get(url, headers=headers)  
#print(response.text)

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/live-analysis-variations?index=gainers&type=NIFTY&csv=true'
response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
response.encoding = "utf-8-sig"
gainers = response.text
print('\n--- gainers ---\n')
print(gainers)

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/live-analysis-variations?index=loosers&type=NIFTY&csv=true'
response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
response.encoding = "utf-8-sig"
loosers = response.text
print('\n--- loosers ---\n')

First: it needs header User-Agent to download get anything form server. If you don't have this header then it hangs.
Second: it needs to get main page before downloading - probably to get some cookies.
Third: it gives text with ï»¿ at the beginning - it is BOM (Byte Order Mark). You need to use encoding utf-8-sig to skip it
This gives me:
--- gainers ---

"Symbol","Open","High","Low","Prev. Close","LTP","%chng","Volume","Value","CA "
"BAJFINANCE",6840.05,7150,6810.05,6893.2,7110,3.15,1218375,8520583725,"30-Jun-2023"
"M&M",2034,2087,1998.2,2024.95,2084,2.92,3253248,6691117824,"14-Jul-2023"
"HDFCBANK",1486.55,1534.95,1480.25,1494.7,1534.2,2.64,17288217,26183869057.35,"16-May-2023"
"MARUTI",12399.9,12759.4,12225,12405,12690,2.3,635535,7949392531.65,"03-Aug-2023"
"JSWSTEEL",842.85,867.3,833.2,844.8,864,2.27,3157898,2697823840.38,"11-Jul-2023"
"BHARTIARTL",1280,1296.5,1253.35,1265.75,1289.95,1.91,13103862,16751846142.18,"11-Aug-2023"
"GRASIM",2220,2290.75,2201.35,2226.05,2266.9,1.84,1061064,2394651677.76,"10-Jan-2024"
"WIPRO",440,453.9,437,444.35,452.1,1.74,10235053,4572612278.28,"24-Jan-2024"
"BAJAJFINSV",1587,1628.75,1568.7,1593.9,1618.6,1.55,1242066,1990398344.34,"30-Jun-2023"
"APOLLOHOSP",6140,6199,6050,6074.15,6155,1.33,560178,3437179384.86,"20-Feb-2024"
"ITC",418,426.25,416,418.85,424,1.23,16582634,7025067067.76,"08-Feb-2024"
"ICICIBANK",1052.95,1072,1048.1,1055.45,1068,1.19,11284433,11984406378.99,"09-Aug-2023"
"ADANIPORTS",1280,1316,1270,1295.55,1310.8,1.18,3899281,5057640406.67,"28-Jul-2023"
"TATASTEEL",160,162.5,157.3,160.05,161.9,1.16,60078229,9640753407.63,"22-Jun-2023"
"TECHM",1163.05,1204.85,1162.95,1179.65,1192.5,1.09,2572144,3057173194.08,"02-Nov-2023"
"TITAN",3525.1,3571.2,3478.25,3525.1,3562,1.05,1507940,5329859168.2,"13-Jul-2023"
"AXISBANK",1015,1036.95,995.7,1024,1031.7,0.75,21598007,21821762352.52,"07-Jul-2023"
"SBIN",734.5,752,732.05,744.8,750,0.7,10886554,8092302184.82,"31-May-2023"
"HINDUNILVR",2220,2243.75,2196,2214.8,2230,0.69,2337694,5205834145.54,"02-Nov-2023"
"INDUSINDBK",1466,1490.25,1444.4,1474.4,1483,0.58,4311650,6341790402.5,"02-Jun-2023"

--- loosers ---

"Symbol","Open","High","Low","Prev. Close","LTP","%chng","Volume","Value","CA "
"BAJAJ-AUTO",9075.05,9090,8700.05,9021.3,8798,-2.48,1385007,12199363257.12,"29-Feb-2024"
"DIVISLAB",3661,3710.85,3641,3708.9,3660,-1.32,746223,2754876222.48,"11-Aug-2023"
"NESTLEIND",2430,2471.35,2410,2462.55,2430,-1.32,1851012,4510786673.16,"15-Feb-2024"
"HCLTECH",1442,1455.5,1435,1466.85,1449.9,-1.16,5219506,7548762747.56,"19-Jan-2024"
"LT",3525,3542.9,3472.4,3550.95,3512.9,-1.07,2759031,9683536642.56,"12-Sep-2023"
"TCS",3838,3852.55,3800.9,3862,3822.15,-1.03,2957749,11321494157.26,"19-Jan-2024"
"BPCL",578,589.9,564.2,589.6,584.5,-0.86,10498042,6056845331.9,"12-Dec-2023"
"LTIM",4650,4672.6,4596.35,4697.15,4659,-0.81,375613,1743227445.26,"27-Oct-2023"
"HEROMOTOCO",4251.25,4251.25,4168.15,4251.3,4217,-0.81,674079,2834731381.86,"21-Feb-2024"
"HDFCLIFE",600,604.4,581.1,605.65,601.15,-0.74,10243493,6106863221.81,"16-Jun-2023"
"TATAMOTORS",964,967.95,944,971.35,964.4,-0.72,15381310,14706378117.2,"28-Jul-2023"
"COALINDIA",436,438.6,428.05,438.6,435.75,-0.65,7628287,3315558661.68,"20-Feb-2024"
"BRITANNIA",4682.05,4698,4641,4695,4669,-0.55,424834,1985402222.24,"21-Aug-2023"
"INFY",1385,1426.85,1378.75,1419.25,1411.95,-0.51,20603621,28860934188.17,"25-Oct-2023"
"NTPC",343.1,352.4,343,351.15,349.5,-0.47,12867942,4484349107.58,"06-Feb-2024"
"DRREDDY",6000,6000,5880.8,5957.15,5940,-0.29,342651,2030988419.28,"11-Jul-2023"
"EICHERMOT",4345,4369.45,4261.3,4351.2,4340.05,-0.26,719002,3106534421.24,"14-Aug-2023"
"CIPLA",1347,1357.7,1335,1347.3,1347,-0.02,1173025,1579220097,"21-Jul-2023"
"SHRIRAMFIN",2349.85,2378.65,2325.1,2371.45,2371.05,-0.02,959432,2256967836.8,"06-Feb-2024"

Using io I can load it to pandas
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.text))

print(df)

Result:
--- gainers ---

        Symbol      Open      High       Low  Prev. Close       LTP  %chng    Volume         Value          CA 
0   BAJFINANCE   6840.05   7150.00   6810.05      6893.20   7110.00   3.15   1218375  8.520584e+09  30-Jun-2023
1          M&M   2034.00   2087.00   1998.20      2024.95   2084.00   2.92   3253248  6.691118e+09  14-Jul-2023
2     HDFCBANK   1486.55   1534.95   1480.25      1494.70   1534.20   2.64  17288217  2.618387e+10  16-May-2023
3       MARUTI  12399.90  12759.40  12225.00     12405.00  12690.00   2.30    635535  7.949393e+09  03-Aug-2023
4     JSWSTEEL    842.85    867.30    833.20       844.80    864.00   2.27   3157898  2.697824e+09  11-Jul-2023
5   BHARTIARTL   1280.00   1296.50   1253.35      1265.75   1289.95   1.91  13103862  1.675185e+10  11-Aug-2023
6       GRASIM   2220.00   2290.75   2201.35      2226.05   2266.90   1.84   1061064  2.394652e+09  10-Jan-2024
7        WIPRO    440.00    453.90    437.00       444.35    452.10   1.74  10235053  4.572612e+09  24-Jan-2024
8   BAJAJFINSV   1587.00   1628.75   1568.70      1593.90   1618.60   1.55   1242066  1.990398e+09  30-Jun-2023
9   APOLLOHOSP   6140.00   6199.00   6050.00      6074.15   6155.00   1.33    560178  3.437179e+09  20-Feb-2024
10         ITC    418.00    426.25    416.00       418.85    424.00   1.23  16582634  7.025067e+09  08-Feb-2024
11   ICICIBANK   1052.95   1072.00   1048.10      1055.45   1068.00   1.19  11284433  1.198441e+10  09-Aug-2023
12  ADANIPORTS   1280.00   1316.00   1270.00      1295.55   1310.80   1.18   3899281  5.057640e+09  28-Jul-2023
13   TATASTEEL    160.00    162.50    157.30       160.05    161.90   1.16  60078229  9.640753e+09  22-Jun-2023
14       TECHM   1163.05   1204.85   1162.95      1179.65   1192.50   1.09   2572144  3.057173e+09  02-Nov-2023
15       TITAN   3525.10   3571.20   3478.25      3525.10   3562.00   1.05   1507940  5.329859e+09  13-Jul-2023
16    AXISBANK   1015.00   1036.95    995.70      1024.00   1031.70   0.75  21598007  2.182176e+10  07-Jul-2023
17        SBIN    734.50    752.00    732.05       744.80    750.00   0.70  10886554  8.092302e+09  31-May-2023
18  HINDUNILVR   2220.00   2243.75   2196.00      2214.80   2230.00   0.69   2337694  5.205834e+09  02-Nov-2023
19  INDUSINDBK   1466.00   1490.25   1444.40      1474.40   1483.00   0.58   4311650  6.341790e+09  02-Jun-2023

--- loosers ---

        Symbol     Open     High      Low  Prev. Close      LTP  %chng    Volume         Value          CA 
0   BAJAJ-AUTO  9075.05  9090.00  8700.05      9021.30  8798.00  -2.48   1385007  1.219936e+10  29-Feb-2024
1     DIVISLAB  3661.00  3710.85  3641.00      3708.90  3660.00  -1.32    746223  2.754876e+09  11-Aug-2023
2    NESTLEIND  2430.00  2471.35  2410.00      2462.55  2430.00  -1.32   1851012  4.510787e+09  15-Feb-2024
3      HCLTECH  1442.00  1455.50  1435.00      1466.85  1449.90  -1.16   5219506  7.548763e+09  19-Jan-2024
4           LT  3525.00  3542.90  3472.40      3550.95  3512.90  -1.07   2759031  9.683537e+09  12-Sep-2023
5          TCS  3838.00  3852.55  3800.90      3862.00  3822.15  -1.03   2957749  1.132149e+10  19-Jan-2024
6         BPCL   578.00   589.90   564.20       589.60   584.50  -0.86  10498042  6.056845e+09  12-Dec-2023
7         LTIM  4650.00  4672.60  4596.35      4697.15  4659.00  -0.81    375613  1.743227e+09  27-Oct-2023
8   HEROMOTOCO  4251.25  4251.25  4168.15      4251.30  4217.00  -0.81    674079  2.834731e+09  21-Feb-2024
9     HDFCLIFE   600.00   604.40   581.10       605.65   601.15  -0.74  10243493  6.106863e+09  16-Jun-2023
10  TATAMOTORS   964.00   967.95   944.00       971.35   964.40  -0.72  15381310  1.470638e+10  28-Jul-2023
11   COALINDIA   436.00   438.60   428.05       438.60   435.75  -0.65   7628287  3.315559e+09  20-Feb-2024
12   BRITANNIA  4682.05  4698.00  4641.00      4695.00  4669.00  -0.55    424834  1.985402e+09  21-Aug-2023
13        INFY  1385.00  1426.85  1378.75      1419.25  1411.95  -0.51  20603621  2.886093e+10  25-Oct-2023
14        NTPC   343.10   352.40   343.00       351.15   349.50  -0.47  12867942  4.484349e+09  06-Feb-2024
15     DRREDDY  6000.00  6000.00  5880.80      5957.15  5940.00  -0.29    342651  2.030988e+09  11-Jul-2023
16   EICHERMOT  4345.00  4369.45  4261.30      4351.20  4340.05  -0.26    719002  3.106534e+09  14-Aug-2023
17       CIPLA  1347.00  1357.70  1335.00      1347.30  1347.00  -0.02   1173025  1.579220e+09  21-Jul-2023
18  SHRIRAMFIN  2349.85  2378.65  2325.10      2371.45  2371.05  -0.02    959432  2.256968e+09  06-Feb-2024


If you change type= in url then you can get data for other Index
Like BANK NIFTY:
https://www.nseindia.com/api/live-analysis-variations?index=loosers&type=BANKNIFTY&csv=true

thanks for sharing the code snippet, @furas. It, however, is giving the "Resource not found" error.

@Tanmoy this code works for me - but maybe it blocks access from some world's regions (I tested it from Poland, Europe), or it may block when you get it very often. As I said it has to use User-Agent  and get full page  because it may need cookies to work correctly, but it may have other system to detect scripts/bots/hackers/spamers and it may need to use Selenium instead of requests
